# Kubernetes pod: node application restarting for every 15 mins

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, npm

I have a node applications deployed using Kubernetes, but it's getting restarted exactly for every 15 mins.

```
Below is the error that is logged before it is restarting.

npm ERR! path /home/node/source
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! signal SIGTERM
npm ERR! command sh -c -- nodemon .
```

I thought it might be restarting due to `nodemon`, I have tried using `node` also, but still the same behavior.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the events in the deployment's namespace? `kubectl get events -n $node_namespace` That should provide you and us with some more clues.

Comment: I have ran this command `kubectl get events -n api-blender` where `api-blender` is node namespace. This gave result as `No resources found in api-blender namespace` @Alwyn

Comment: An image has an immutable copy of its application, so there's not really a point to using live-reloading tools like Nodemon here.  That may or may not help – absent a [mcve] it's hard to say what might be going wrong – but it might help you remove one variable from the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

The issue due to misconfiguration of livenessprob health check api. As application is not responding for the kubernetes health api, kubernetes is restarting the pod.